# standard deviation of two samples

Tags: statistics

there are two samples, both with standard deviation 8.5.
If one combines the two samples together, find the relation between the standard deviation and 17.

I figure it cannot be determined. But I am not sure how to argue rigorously. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Start with the definition of standard deviation. What happens if you merge two sets of samples? What becomes of the standard deviation then?

Comment: You might want to take a loot at this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55999/224433

Comment: @ Matti P    Hi! Thank you! I also checked the link below. So it indeed cannot be determined. Is it correct? Thank you again